# calculation returns large negative number

Tags: c++

Everything is working as it should, but every time I try to calculate the sales total for the number of seats sold in coach, I get a large negative number.

I think I'm missing a declaration for an initial value somewhere, but any changes I make don't seem to help.
I feel like the issues is hiding out in my void totalSales, but I could be wrong. Any advice?

```
    void totalSales(char seats[15][6], double seatRates[15])
    {
      double sales = 0;
      int row, i, j;
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
      {
        row = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (seats[i][j] == '*')
            {
                row++;
            }
        }
        sales += row * seatRates[i];
    }

    cout << "\n\nTotal Sales : $" << sales << "\n";
    }

EDIT: 


void seatingChart(char seats[15][6])
{
    int i;
    cout << "\n\nSeating Chart:\n";
    cout << "\n        First Class\n";
    cout << "\n \t1  2\t3  4\n";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Row " << i + 1 << ":\t";
        cout << seats[i][0] << " " << seats[i][1] << "\t";
        cout << seats[i][2] << " " << seats[i][3] << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n             Coach\n";
    cout << "\n\t1 2 3\t4 5 6\n";
    for (i = 5; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << "Row " << i + 1 << ":\t";
        cout << seats[i][0] << " " << seats[i][1] << " " << seats[i][2] << "\t";
        cout << seats[i][3] << " " << seats[i][4] << " " << seats[i][5] << "\n";
    }
}

void reserveSeat(char seats[15][6])
{
    int row = 0, seat = 0;
    while (seat == 0 && row == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n\nSelect a Seat\n";
        cout << "First Class (1 - 5), Coach (6 - 15)\n";
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> row;
        if (row <= 5)
        {
            cout << "Seat (1 - 4): ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Seat (1 - 6) : ";
        }
        cin >> seat;
        if (row < 1 || row > 15 || seat < 1 || seat > 6 || seats[row - 1][seat - 1] == '@')
        {
            cout << "Invalid Selection.\n";
            seat = 0; row = 0;
        }
        else if (seats[row - 1][seat - 1] == '*')
        {
            cout << "Selected Seat Unavailable. Please choose another seat.\n";
            seat = 0; row = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            seats[row - 1][seat - 1] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void totalSales(char seats[15][6], double seatRates[15]) // There is something wrong with my sales calculations.
{
    double sales = 0;
    int row, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        row = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (seats[i][j] == '*')
            {
                row++;
            }
        }
        sales += row * seatRates[i];
    }
    cout << "\n\nTotal Sales : $" << sales << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The code shown looks OK to me. The problem likely lies in the code not shown; e.g. `seatRates` may not be initialized correctly and contains garbage. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Print out `seatrRates` and confirm that they are values you expect

Comment: This sounds like a time to use a debugger to pin down exactly when and where the program does something you didn't expect.

Comment: *Everything is working as it should* -- But you are saying the program doesn't behave correctly.  So how is the program "working as it should"?